# Retrieve image from database in mvc.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been looking for this solution for days already, but nothing was satisfactory.

In my database, I have images stored under this command:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Jogo]
SET Capa = (SELECT 'metal-gear-solid.jpg' FROM OPENROWSET(BULK      
N'G:\Imagens\Desenvolvimento\Locadora\metal-gear-solid.jpg', 
SINGLE_BLOB) rs) 
WHERE IdJogo = 3
GO
```

But when I try to retrieve them, all I get is a broken image icon.
When I converted into base 64 I got a result like this:

> The view 'data:image/jpeg;base64,UmF0Y2hldF8mX0NsYW5rX0Z1dHVyZS5qcGc=' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

Also, when I try to convert it into an image object (Image, Bitmap, WebImage, etc.) I get this:

> An image could not be constructed from the content provided.

I believe the images are not properly stored, even though I checked the path and the images are all there. This is as one image is in the database (SQL SERVER, image type): 0x526174636865745F265F436C616E6B5F4675747572652E6A7067

This is my action:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        LocadoraEntities context = new LocadoraEntities();
        using (context)
        {
            var listaBytes = context.Jogo.Select(c =>  
            c.Capa).FirstOrDefault();

            byte[] ms = listaBytes.ToArray();

            string imagemConvertida = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,      
            {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(ms));


            return View(imagemConvertida);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you storing it as a byte array? I don't see you doing that

Comment: Why not store the image as a base64?

Comment: You're returning a `View` with some name (the string) - as shown in the first error. Did you intend that data to be in `ViewBag` instead - e.g. `<img src="@ViewBag.foo"  />` ?

Comment: As far as I saw, that is the standard for storing images straight from the database. And I tried storing in a ViewBag too, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, the images were not properly stored, as I tried inserting them through application and it worked smoothly. I will have to review the insert proc.

Thank you for your answers.